# VC++ 2010 error in C struct malloc code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, struct, malloc

Please consider the following C code in VC++2010 for creating BST in C language. By creating win32 console application in VC++ project.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct BSTNode
{
    char *data;
    struct BSTNode *left,*right;

}Node;

Node *createNode(char *str)
{
    int strLength=strlen(str);
    char *data=(char *)malloc(strLength+1);
    strcpy(data,str);
    data[strLength+1]='\0';

    Node *temp=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->left=0;
    temp->right=0;
    temp->data=data;

    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    Node *root=createNode("Ravinder");

    printf("%s\n",root->data);
    return 0;
}
```

It give errors in VC++2010:

```
warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.    c:\users\radha krishna\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\binarysearchtree\binarysearchtree\main.c   17
warning C4047: 'return' : 'Node *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'  c:\users\radha krishna\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\binarysearchtree\binarysearchtree\main.c   25
error C2275: 'Node' : illegal use of this type as an expression c:\users\radha krishna\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\binarysearchtree\binarysearchtree\main.c   20
error C2223: left of '->right' must point to struct/union   c:\users\radha krishna\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\binarysearchtree\binarysearchtree\main.c   22
error C2223: left of '->left' must point to struct/union    c:\users\radha krishna\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\binarysearchtree\binarysearchtree\main.c   21
error C2223: left of '->data' must point to struct/union    c:\users\radha krishna\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\binarysearchtree\binarysearchtree\main.c   23
error C2065: 'temp' : undeclared identifier c:\users\radha krishna\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\binarysearchtree\binarysearchtree\main.c   20
error C2065: 'temp' : undeclared identifier c:\users\radha krishna\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\binarysearchtree\binarysearchtree\main.c   21
error C2065: 'temp' : undeclared identifier c:\users\radha krishna\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\binarysearchtree\binarysearchtree\main.c   22
```

But if i replace above function createnode by this it work fine:

```
Node *createNode(char *str)
{
    Node *temp=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->left=0;
    temp->right=0;
    temp->data=str;

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Declaration of variables to collect in the first of block. and delete `data[strLength+1]='\0';` .

Comment: This is C. Declare `Node *temp` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: @barakmanos: that should read: "This is C89" - modern C compilers support C99 at least - only MSVC still lives in the Dark Ages.

Answer (score 4):

MSVC 2010 does not support the modern dialects of C such as C99 - it is still only C89, so you need to move all variable declarations to the start of your function, e.g. a cleaned up version of your function might look like this:

```
Node *createNode(const char *str)
{
    int strLength = strlen(str);
    char *data = malloc(strLength + 1);
    Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));

    strcpy(data, str); 

    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->data = data;

    return temp;
}
```

Note there was a serious bug here:

```
data[strLength+1]='\0';
```

which would have caused an invalid write to unallocated memory.

This should have been:

```
data[strLength]='\0';
```

However this operation is redundant anyway, as `strcpy` will already have written `'\0'` at the end of the string, so you might as well just delete this line.

Note also that you are casting the result of `malloc` in many places - this is [redundant and potentially dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) - you should remove these casts.

Comment: This is a runtime bug. OP is complaining about compilation errors.

Comment: OK - I thought that was already covered in the comments, but I've added it to my answer in addition to the run-time bug.

Comment: @RavinderPatel After this change it should work fine.